# HTML nested <ul> Tags are breaking PDF generation with Html2Pdf

Tags: php, html, html2pdf

I am trying to convert HTML saved in database to pdf using https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/:

```
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output();
```

The HTML:

```
$html = '
<ul>
    <li><strong>Header</strong></li> 
<ul>
    <li>Tag1</li> 
    <li>Tag2</li>
    <li>Tag3<br /></li> 
<ul>
    <li>Tag4</li> 
    <li>Tag5</li> 
</ul>
    <li>Tag6</li>
</ul> 
</ul>';
```

This HTML code leads to overlapping text.
Is there a way to clean those nested tags?

Comment: what's the output?

Comment: Try putting the inner `ul`s into a parent `li`.